# wp_postmeta store multiple values in one key

Tags: post-meta, array

I am currently storing some data in a custom field like this:

```
$get_ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$ref = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_ref', true );
$ref[] = $get_ref;
update_post_meta($post->ID,'page_ref', $ref);
```

The above updates the post_meta but doesnt overide it. I would like to save additional data to the same value that is saved above.

The above produces this:

```
Array ( [0] => http://test.com [1] => http://website.com )
```

I would like something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => array(http://test.com, 14/04/2014) [1] => array(http://website.com, 10/01/2014));
```

Any ideas how i can achieve this?

Comment: This is basic PHP array manipulation and doesn't look WordPress specific at all to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly you want an array of arrays.

```
$get_ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$ref = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_ref', true );
$ref[] = array($get_ref); //or $ref[][] = 'xyz' ...if you prefer
update_post_meta($post->ID,'page_ref', $ref);
```